# POST data through Ajax without using JQuery methods

Tags: ajax, post

I've an Ajax code, through which i want to send securely a private access_token to a url via http POST, how to achieve this using below given code??

```
function getstatus(url, placeid, access_token)
        {
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if(window.ActiveXObject)
            {
                try
                {
                xmlRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxm12.xMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                    xmlRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                        xmlRequest = false;
                    }
                }
            }


            xmlRequest.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
                                    {
                                        if(xmlRequest.readyState==4)
                                        {
                                            if(placeid == "adminstatus")
                                            adminstatus.innerHTML=xmlRequest.responseText;

                                            if(placeid == "dbview")
                                            {
                                            dbview.innerHTML=xmlRequest.responseText;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
            xmlRequest.send();
        }
```

Consider the parameter "access_token" in the function getstatus is to be http POST-ed!

Comment: Why don't you want to use jQuery? It will shield you from browser differences which can be a huge pain and barrier for your development. As a second remark, if you want to send a private token, you should certainly do it over https and not http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest), assuming you are attempting to send the data as key/value pairs,

```
xmlRequest.open("POST",url,true);//use the post method
xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");//set the content type
...
xmlRequest.send("access_token="+encodeURIComponent(access_token));//send the token
```